# QFont::setPointSize: Point size <= 0 (-1), must be greater than 0

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I did a mainwindow.ui file converted into Ui_mainwindow.py (pyuic4). 
Next I used the class from this .py file like this:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MainWindow()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run the code in ipython, the following message appeared:
QFont::setPointSize: Point size <= 0 (-1), must be greater than 0

Here the .ui link:
[mainwindow.ui](http://txtup.net/DDvZH)
Here the .py from .ui link:
[Ui_mainwindow.py](http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=GFCG)

ipython terminal remain in bug state even if the app works.
When I quit app (No error or warnings), ipython is still in this state.

Here the link picture bug:[ipython bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYYYh.png)
[image: ipython bug]

Could someone explain me how to avoid it?

Comment: What are the contents of the file compiled with pyuic? You have probably set some property with an invalid value.

Comment: @Bakuriu: As you suggest, I add Ui_mainwindow.py. Thank you

Comment: @Bakuriu: I found where come from the message : font.setPointSize(-1) -> font.setPointSize(1). But the bug don't come from this message because after changing bug still remains.

Comment: I believe the error is due to that line. You probably recompilied the UI, thus the change you have made to the `.py` file is removed. Open the designer, find the settings for the font and change the size to a positive value.

Comment: It seems that i can't change this value. It appears on font: A [Ubuntu, -1].

Comment: Your files's links are broken.

Comment: Hi @Katsu, could you please fix these links?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `<pointsize>-1</pointsize>` tag from the font tag in your .ui file to prevent this error.

Beware that this will make QT Creator/Designer not load the font attribute, so name the file without the pointsizes something different.